# How to add sum of same objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, logic, lodash

I am new to development.

I want to group the same objects inside array of json objects. E.g. here is my JSON array:

```
var data = [
    {
        zone: "Bottom",
        group: "Bottom girders",
        original: 7,
        gauge: 3,
        dPercent: 0,
        permissible: 10,
    },
    {
        zone: "Bottom",
        group: "Bottom girders",
        original: 9,
        gauge: 7,
        dPercent: 0,
        permissible: 10,
    },
    {
        zone: "Bottom",
        group: "risers",
        original: 7,
        gauge: 3,
        dPercent: 0,
        permissible: 10,
    },
    {
        zone: "Neutral axis",
        group: "Transverse PSM",
        original: 17,
        gauge: 28,
        dPercent: 0,
        permissible: 15,
    },
    {
        zone: "Neutral axis",
        group: "Transverse PSM",
        original: 17,
        gauge: 12,
        dPercent: 0,
        permissible: 15,
    },
];
```

The final output I expect is:

```
[
      {
        "zone": "Neutral Axis",
        "groups": [
           { "zone":"Bottom", "group":"Bottom girders","original": 34, "gauge": 40, "dPercent": 5.3, "permissible": 10 }
        ]
      },
      {
        "zone": "Bottom",
        "groups": [
           { "zone":"Bottom", "group":"Bottom girders", "original": 16, "gauge": 10, "dPercent": 5.3, "permissible": 10 },
           { "zone":"Bottom", "group":"risers", "original": 7, "gauge": 3, "dPercent": 5.3, "permissible": 10 }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Logic:
I want to club data **zone** wise first then each **zone** having different **group** and based on group i want to add **original** and **gauge** values final output as shown

Here is my code link i have tried
https://angular-ivy-zm5kqo.stackblitz.io

***Thank you so much in Advance !***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your output example I suppose that you want group your entities by their `zone` property, and get result as an array.

The code that do it:

```
var data = [/*your data here*/];

var groupedData = _.groupBy(data, 'zone');
var result = _.map(groupedData, (value, key) => {
  return {
    "zone": key,
    "groups": value
  }
});
```

It can be chained, if you like that way:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
  .groupBy('zone')
  .map((value, key) => {
    return {
      "zone": key,
      "groups": value
    }
  }).value();
```

`_.groupBy` transforms your data array into object like this:

```
{
   "Bottom":[
      /* All entities where zone is "Bottom" */
   ],
   "Neutral axis":[
      /* All entities where zone is "Neutral axis" */
   ]
}
```

Then we transform this object into array of your desired objects using `_.map`.

Resources:

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is:

1. group by `zone` attribute
2. then in each group, nested group by `group` attribute
3. and then for each group you want the `zone` as key `zone` value and
   a `groups` key as a array value for all the nested groups.
4. and in each nested group you want `zone`, `grroup` value
   straightaway and sum of all other 4 attributes 4 that nested group
   for each key (`original`, `original`, `original`, `original`)

Lets do the same in a snippet easily:

```js
const data = [{"zone":"Bottom","group":"Bottom girders","original":7,"gauge":3,"dPercent":0,"permissible":10},{"zone":"Bottom","group":"Bottom girders","original":9,"gauge":7,"dPercent":0,"permissible":10},{"zone":"Bottom","group":"risers","original":7,"gauge":3,"dPercent":0,"permissible":10},{"zone":"Neutral axis","group":"Transverse PSM","original":17,"gauge":28,"dPercent":0,"permissible":15},{"zone":"Neutral axis","group":"Transverse PSM","original":17,"gauge":12,"dPercent":0,"permissible":15}];

var res = _(data)
    .groupBy('zone')
    .map((grp, zone) => ({
        zone,
        groups: _(grp).groupBy('group').map((nestGrp, group) => ({
            zone,
            group,
            original: _.sumBy(nestGrp, 'original'),
            gauge: _.sumBy(nestGrp, 'gauge'),
            dPercent: _.sumBy(nestGrp, 'dPercent'),
            permissible: _.sumBy(nestGrp, 'permissible')
        })).value()
    })).value();
    
 console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```